# Unable to trash files accross filesystem boundaries when using Thunar

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, thunar

I have an XFCE container with 2 mounts `--bind` : `/home` and `/home/collab`. `/home/collab` is meant to be a shared directory where everyone has access.

Each time I try to move a file from `/home/collab` to the trash (action for the delete key in Thunar), I have this error :

> "Unable to trash file `/home/collab/<filename>` across filesystem boundaries."

It seems like Thunar can't deal with 2 bind mounts, and doesn't find the trash.

A possible workaround is to change the action move to trash for a custom script that will just move the file to the right folder, but Thunar doesn't allow to modify default actions, so that would mean recompiling the binary and I don't want that, that's dirty work.

Or I could use a custom action but same problem, I want to delete the move-to-trash default action from the right-click menu in this case, and change the delete shortcut to this action which would mean recompiling.

Another workaround would be to use another file manager but Thunar is lightweight, well integrated with XFCE, and I don't know what else to use.

PS: This container contains an environment used by non-programmers, so I need a very user-friendly interface (gui tools).

Comment: Wish I could help, but I haven't had a file manager installed for the last five years. I hope you can get it to work.  Thunar seems like most sane GUI fm out there. Good luck.

Comment: Did you report a bug for it on https://bugzilla.xfce.org/ ?

Comment: I'm not sure it's a bug, a friend says it has probably something to do with the way the trash is handled and the way gvfs works, so if someone could confirm this is a bug and not intended to work this way, I'd report it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed using only one `bind mount` : `/home`

I would have preferred having the shared directory on a separate mount but that's the only solution I found !

Thanks anyway.